# Service did not respond in a timely fashion - Very large database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a very large sql database that I was trying to switch over to a different computer. When starting sql on that other computer I got the error of 
"service did not respond in a timely fashion".

So I switched the database back to my original computer, got the same error, deleted the ibdata and ib log files and .frm files. Same error.

I assume it's not waiting long enough to read the tables but don't know how to correct this. I read the fixes about VIA protocol but this is not a networked drive, its just connected via usb.

My main concern is that my database will be lost. Please reassure me that if i have the ibd file that my database is still safe.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking I should reimport my ibd file using this method.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-migration.html#copy-tables-cold-backup

Correct?

Edit. I was able to reimport my data using this method. Just had to remake my schema similar enough to the original.